# LAN connection problem

Tags: connection, ethernet, lan

how to connect to  different  system within the lan? im  getting messages back when pinged with host ip address and also for default gateway. But messages pinged to another ip address with in my lan are not comming back?  please help me out.

Comment: Could you provide more information please. Such as what type of systems you are trying to connect, type of LAN etc.

Comment: Is there something else that isn't working, or do you just want ping to work?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details, but it seems like a routing issue.

Maybe you can solve it using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a firewall blocking ping responses.  If you're using a third party firewall, you should temporarily disable it for testing.

If you're only using the default Windows XP firewall, you want to flag ["Allow incoming echo request"](http://www.cam.ac.uk/cs/docs/faq/m8.html) in the firewall ICMP settings.

In Vista or Windows 7, it looks like the easiest way to allow ping is via command prompt:

```
netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8 enable
```